# IE9 crashes when there are over 2^15 absolute positioned elements on page

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, telerik-reporting

We are using Telerik reporting to generate reports on the client. Now, we have some problems in some rare cases with artifacts in the layout and the browser hanging. This happens in IE9 only and not latest Chrome of Firefox.

So I created a small example to test if it had anything to do with the number of elements on the page and discovered that the problem occurs when there are over 2^15 absolute positioned elements. (A lot, yes - but out of my control if we are to keep this framework).

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    for(var i = 0; i < 32768; i++){
        document.write("<div id = 'node" + i + "' style='position:absolute;top:" + i*25 + "'>distance to top: " + i*25 + "</div>");
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'd appreciate confirmation that this is an issue with IE9 and/or suggestions on how to work around it.

Answer (score 0):

Note that 2^15 is 32768, which is the upper limit of a 16-bit integer. In this case it seems that Internet Explorer stores the element hierarchy (DOM, or Document Object Model) as 16-bit integers, hence the limit.

Note that this is not any inherent HTML limit, but merely an implementation limit in IE9. Please try checking in IE10/11, since these browsers increased limits on CSS rules (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/05/14/internet-explorer-stylesheet-rule-selector-import-sheet-limit-maximum.aspx) and maybe DOM elements at the same time.